# R: how to use geom_point to add points to side-by-side error bars

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

```
library(tidyverse)

library(ggplot2)
x <- c(3.409091, 4.090909, 4.772728, 5.454546)
data <- structure(list(approach1 = c(1.02967633502518, 1.01580726843304, 1.04284139608584, 
                                     1.04357840118423), approach2 = c(1.0173503641109, 1.00394712634612, 
                                                                      1.02773624467658, 1.02863476832808)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                -4L))

data.lower <- structure(list(approach1 = c(1.0115541354025, 0.993078788685045, 1.01974099190034, 
                                           1.02080115708828), approach2 = c(0.997978808683001, 0.982131487818724, 
                                                                            1.00420304483585, 1.00652657076137)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")

data.upper <- structure(list(approach1 = c(1.05177371364311, 1.03851495380357, 1.06108886027293, 
                                           1.06774282552092), approach2 = c(1.03841840431302, 1.0260370212124, 
                                                                            1.04663363856828, 1.0525347857539)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")


bind_cols(
  data %>% mutate(x = x) %>% pivot_longer(-x, values_to = "data"),
  data.lower %>% pivot_longer(everything()) %>% select(lower = value),
  data.upper %>% pivot_longer(everything()) %>% select(upper = value)
) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, data, color = name, ymin = lower, ymax = upper)) +
  geom_errorbar(position = "dodge")
```

The error bars correspond to the data in `data.lower` and `data.upper`. I would also like to add a point to each error bar. The data for this is stored in `data`. I've tried the following, but it did not seem to work, as the points are not on the actual error bars:

```
 bind_cols(
      data %>% mutate(x = x) %>% pivot_longer(-x, values_to = "data"),
      data.lower %>% pivot_longer(everything()) %>% select(lower = value),
      data.upper %>% pivot_longer(everything()) %>% select(upper = value)
    ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, data, color = name, ymin = lower, ymax = upper)) +
  geom_errorbar(position = "dodge") + geom_point(aes(x = x, y = data))
```

[image]

Comment: Try with `geom_errorbar(position = position_dodge(width = 0.6)) + geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.6))`. In your case you don't need to specify the aesthetics again in geom_point. And if so you have to wrap them in `aes()`. The position_dodge makes sure that your points align with error bars.

Comment: Thank you. Would you like to post this as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you don't need to specify the aesthetics again in `geom_point`. And if so you have to wrap them in `aes()`. That's the main issue with your code. Additionally to make sure that the points align with the error bars you have to set the same positioning (and width) via `position_dodge`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

bind_cols(
  data %>% mutate(x = x) %>% pivot_longer(-x, values_to = "data"),
  data.lower %>% pivot_longer(everything()) %>% select(lower = value),
  data.upper %>% pivot_longer(everything()) %>% select(upper = value)
) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, data, color = name, ymin = lower, ymax = upper)) +
  geom_errorbar(position = position_dodge(width = 0.6)) + 
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.6))
```

[image]